# Returning data from activity to fragment

Tags: java, android, android-activity, fragment

I'm opening an Activity on fragment view touch. how to get data back to the fragment which opens the Activity.

Comment: `onActivityResult` might help!

Comment: `startActuivityForResult`/`onActivityResult`

Comment: Remember to startActivity from fragment with fragment context to get the call direcly in the fragment like MyFragment.this.startActivtiyForResult(intent,12);

Answer (score 1):

1- First you'll have to start the Activity from your fragment using `startActivityForResult()`

2- Make sure to call `super.onActivityResult` in your Activity's `onActivityResult()` method ( if you're implementing it)

3-Inside your fragment, you just need to implement `onActivityResult()` and handle the result as you wish

Answer (score 0):

To get data from your activity to your intent put it as an extra like:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyIntent.class);
intent.putExtra("aString", aString);
intent.putExtra("aSomething", customSerializableType);
startActivityForResult(intent, MY_REQUEST_ID);
```

In the Intent get it out like:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    ...

    Intent intent = getIntent();

    String newString = intent.getStringExtra("aString");
    CustomSerializableType newSomething = intent.getSerializableExtra("aSomething");
}
```

From your intent send data back with:

```
private void done() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("aString", aString);
    intent.putExtra("aSomething", customSerializableType);

    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
    finish();
}
```

And get that data out in the hosting activity with

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
  switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_REQUEST_ID:
      if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String newString = data.getStringExtra("aString");
        CustomSerializableType newSomething = data.getSerializableExtra("aSomething");
      }
      break;
}
```