# My home nav button keeps adding notes instead of my add note menu button

Tags: android

i made a Fragment and divided it to 3 parts , home , search, favourite
this is my mainActivity code

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
BottomNavigationView navigationView;
Fragment selected;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer,new Home()).commit();
        navigationView=findViewById(R.id.nav);
        navigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem menuItem) {
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case R.id.navHome:
                        selected =  new Home();
                        break;

                    case R.id.navFavorite:
                        selected = new Fav();
                        break;

                    case R.id.navSearch:
                        selected = new Search();
                        break;
                }

                
          getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frameContainer,selected).commit();



                       return true;
            }
        });
        
    }

}
```

and made it that my Home Fragment shall contain an array where my notes that i will be adding and storing
and finally made another menutoolBar and aligned at the top thats my add button where when i click it its supposed to add a new note and then i can go and edit it as i want
now what strange is that everytime i click the home button it adds a note and my add button note is not functionning
this is my Home Fragment code

```
    public class Home extends Fragment {
    static ArrayList<String> notes = new ArrayList<String>();
    static ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter;
    @Nullable
    @Override

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.home, container, false);

        return myView;
    }
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        ListView listView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);

        notes.add("Example note");
         arrayAdapter =new ArrayAdapter(getContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,notes);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
      listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {//edit
          @Override
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int i, long id) {
              Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),NoteEditorActivity.class);
              intent.putExtra("noteId",i);
              startActivity(intent);
          }
      });
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
       inflater.inflate(R.menu.add_note_menu, menu) ;

        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        if(item.getItemId()==R.id.add_note){
            Intent intent =new Intent(getActivity(),NoteEditorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);


        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

and this is where i am editing the note and opening a new intent

```
    public class NoteEditorActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    int noteId;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {//made a new intent that shows the text we write
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_editor);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextTextMultiLine);
        Intent intent=getIntent();
         noteId=intent.getIntExtra("noteId",-1);
        if(noteId!=-1){
            editText.setText(Home.notes.get(noteId));
        } else {
             Home.notes.add("");
           noteId=Home.notes.size()-1;
            Home.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {//changing the text in the note
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
             Home.notes.set(noteId,String.valueOf(s));
             Home.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

i tried to change around the `selected=new Home();` but to no success except when i made it only add one note once every time i went to another page and clicked back on Home but other than that could not fix the problem
and help and suggestions and hints are welcome and thanks in advance

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
android:id="@+id/navHome"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_home_24"
    android:title="Home"
    />

<item
    android:id="@+id/navSearch"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_search_24"
    android:title="Search"

    />


    <item
        android:id="@+id/navFavorite"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_baseline_favorite_24"
        android:title="Favorite"

        />



</menu>
```

this is my xml file

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item android:id="@+id/add_note"
        android:title="Add Note"

        />

</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are adding the note in `onViewCreated` which gets called every time you create the home fragment.

Here is a way to return data back from the opened activity to fragment:
[Returning data from activity to fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54866984/returning-data-from-activity-to-fragment)